# Rails CSRF with json requests

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, json, csrf

Is there a way to make post/put/patch/delete requests from an android application to my rails application which responds with json files and at the same time have CSRF active on my server?

So in other words I want to have protection from forgery when making requests from my android app since it will have an ability to modify the webapp data.

Answer (score 1):

I think an impractical solution would be to create a method that outputs a CSRF token, and load this prior to each post/put request.

I usually take a different approach on my APIs that handle sensitive data though - I bypass CSRF and I use SSL for everything, validate certificates, and always post a checksum (based on a static API key and a hash for the current user which I output at login time) of the request which I verify on the server side before processing.